# Compiling CUDA-code to a static library (.a) on linux

Tags: c, cuda, static-linking

I'm trying to compile a small library containing CUDA code.

I have succesfully compiled it as a shared lib, but what I actually need is a static lib.

I have two source files:

- **main.c**: containing a test function written in C. I compile this file with gcc
- **main_kernel.cu**: containing a CUDA-kernel 'testKernel' and a C-wrapper function 'test_gpu' that calls into testKernel.

Here is an excerpt of **main_kernel.cu**:

```
__global__ void testKernel(float *data, const int l)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    if (idx < l)
        data[idx]++;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
void test_gpu(float *data, const int length)
{
    // Run kernel
    testKernel<<< 512, 1024 >>>(data, length);
}
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

I use gcc to compile **main.c** into **main.o** <- This works as desired.

I compile **main_kernel.cu** with nvcc using the -rdc=true option into an intermediate object I call **main_kernel_h.o**.

I then use nvcc with the -dlink option to device-link the intermediate object into **main_kernel.o**.

Then I, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893588/creating-a-static-cuda-library-to-be-linked-with-a-c-program?newreg=10875bc67e6f42dd98c86b4767abb0fa), I link all three into a static lib with ar using the rcs flags.

This all runs fine, but the problem arises when I want to link an executable to the new library.

I then get undefined references for a bunch of CUDA-functions. Here is the exact error:

```
../../build/test/bin/libLib.a(main_kernel_h.o): In function `__nv_cudaEntityRegisterCallback(void**)':
tmpxft_0000422a_00000000-5_main_kernel.compute_52.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x60): undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterFunction'
../../build/test/bin/libLib.a(main_kernel_h.o): In function `__device_stub__Z10testKernelPfi(float*, int)':
tmpxft_0000422a_00000000-5_main_kernel.compute_52.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to `cudaSetupArgument'
tmpxft_0000422a_00000000-5_main_kernel.compute_52.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xb0): undefined reference to `cudaSetupArgument'
tmpxft_0000422a_00000000-5_main_kernel.compute_52.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xc7): undefined reference to `cudaLaunch'
../../build/test/bin/libLib.a(main_kernel_h.o): In function `test_gpu':
tmpxft_0000422a_00000000-5_main_kernel.compute_52.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x124): undefined reference to `cudaConfigureCall'
../../build/test/bin/libLib.a(main_kernel.o): In function `__cudaUnregisterBinaryUtil':
link.stub:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `__cudaUnregisterFatBinary'
../../build/test/bin/libLib.a(main_kernel.o): In function `__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary(__fatBinC_Wrapper_t const*, void (*)(void**), void*)':
link.stub:(.text+0xd0): undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterFatBinary'
```

The ouput I get from **nm** is this:

```
main.o:
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 r .LC0
0000000000000000 T testFunc
                 U test_gpu

main_kernel.o:
                 U atexit
                 U __cudaRegisterFatBinary
0000000000000015 T __cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_57_tmpxft_0000422a_00000000_9_main_kernel_compute_52_cpp1_ii_335679f8
0000000000000000 t __cudaUnregisterBinaryUtil
                 U __cudaUnregisterFatBinary
0000000000000000 r fatbinData
                 U __fatbinwrap_57_tmpxft_0000422a_00000000_9_main_kernel_compute_52_cpp1_ii_335679f8
0000000000000000 r _ZL15__fatDeviceText
0000000000000000 b _ZL20__cudaFatCubinHandle
0000000000000010 b _ZL22__cudaPrelinkedFatbins
000000000000005b t _ZL26__cudaRegisterLinkedBinaryPK19__fatBinC_Wrapper_tPFvPPvES2_
0000000000000000 r _ZL87def_module_id_str_57_tmpxft_0000422a_00000000_9_main_kernel_compute_52_cpp1_ii_335679f8
0000000000000020 b _ZZ96__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_57_tmpxft_0000422a_00000000_9_main_kernel_compute_52_cpp1_ii_335679f8E3__p
0000000000000030 b _ZZL26__cudaRegisterLinkedBinaryPK19__fatBinC_Wrapper_tPFvPPvES2_E16__callback_array
0000000000000028 b _ZZL26__cudaRegisterLinkedBinaryPK19__fatBinC_Wrapper_tPFvPPvES2_E3__i

main_kernel_h.o:
                 U cudaConfigureCall
                 U cudaLaunch
                 U __cudaRegisterFunction
                 U __cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_57_tmpxft_0000422a_00000000_9_main_kernel_compute_52_cpp1_ii_335679f8
                 U cudaSetupArgument
0000000000000000 r fatbinData
0000000000000000 D __fatbinwrap_57_tmpxft_0000422a_00000000_9_main_kernel_compute_52_cpp1_ii_335679f8
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 r .LC0
00000000000000e0 T test_gpu
00000000000000d0 T _Z10testKernelPfi
0000000000000070 T _Z31__device_stub__Z10testKernelPfiPfi
0000000000000000 r _ZL15__module_id_str
0000000000000000 t _ZL22____nv_dummy_param_refPv
0000000000000000 t _ZL24__sti____cudaRegisterAllv
0000000000000010 t _ZL31__nv_cudaEntityRegisterCallbackPPv
0000000000000030 b _ZL32__nv_fatbinhandle_for_managed_rt
0000000000000020 b _ZZ31__device_stub__Z10testKernelPfiPfiE3__f
0000000000000010 b _ZZL22____nv_dummy_param_refPvE5__ref
0000000000000000 b _ZZL31__nv_cudaEntityRegisterCallbackPPvE5__ref
```

If you want my exact commands I have also included the makefiles I use to build the objects;

Makefile for the library:

```
ARCH = -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
       -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
       -gencode arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] \
       -gencode arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52]

VPATH=.
SLIB=libLib.so
ALIB=libLib.a
OBJDIR=../../build/test/bin-int/lib/
OUTDIR=../../build/test/bin/

# Base C-stuff
CC=gcc
CPP=g++
NVCC=nvcc
AR=ar
ARFLAGS=rcs
OPTS=-Ofast
LDFLAGS= -lm -pthread -lc
COMMON= -DEXT_SO
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors

# OPTS=-O0 -g # <- Debug

CFLAGS+=$(OPTS)

# CUDA
COMMON+= -I/usr/local/cuda/include/
LDFLAGS+= -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand

# CUDNN
LDFLAGS+= -lcudnn

# C-objects
OBJ=main.o

# CUDA-objects
# LDFLAGS+= -lstdc++ # <- Unsure if this is required
OBJ_CUDA=main_kernel.o
CUDA_HOST=main_kernel_h.o

OBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR), $(OBJ))
OBJS_CUDA = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR), $(OBJ_CUDA))
OBJS_HOST = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR), $(CUDA_HOST))
DEPS = $(wildcard ./*.h) Makefile

# Build all steps
all: obj $(OBJS) $(OBJS_HOST) $(OBJS_CUDA) $(ALIB)

# Link static lib
$(ALIB): $(OBJS_CUDA) $(OBJS_HOST) $(OBJS)
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $(OUTDIR)$@ $^

# Compile c
$(OBJDIR)%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(COMMON) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

# Compile cuda-hostcode
$(OBJDIR)%_h.o: %.cu $(DEPS)
    $(NVCC) $(ARCH) -c -rdc=true --compiler-options "$(CFLAGS)" $< -o $@

# Device Link device code   
$(OBJDIR)%.o: $(OBJDIR)%_h.o $(DEPS)
    $(NVCC) $(ARCH) -dlink -o $@ $< -lcuda -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand -lcudnn

obj:
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJS) $(ALIB) $(OBJDIR)/*
```

And for the executable trying to link the static library:

```
VPATH=.
EXEC=Test
OBJDIR=../../build/test/bin-int/test/
OUTDIR=../../build/test/bin/
LIB=$(OUTDIR)libLib.a

# Base C-stuff
CC=gcc
CPP=g++
OPTS=-Ofast
LDFLAGS= -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand -lcudnn -Wl,-rpath,'$$ORIGIN' -s
CFLAGS= -MMD -MP -DNDEBUG -DSTRIP_PYTHON -I../src -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors

# OPTS=-O0 -g # <- Debug

CFLAGS+=$(OPTS)

# C-objects
OBJ=test.o

OBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR), $(OBJ))
DEPS = $(wildcard ./*.h) Makefile

# Build all steps
all: obj $(EXEC)

# Link executable
$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $(OUTDIR)$@ $(LDFLAGS) $(LIB)

# Compile c
$(OBJDIR)%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

obj:
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJS) $(OBJDIR)/*
```

I hope you can help me find my mistake(s).

Comment: You don't need and shouldn't use device separate compilation and linking. It is irrelevant in this case

Comment: This looks like a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/16289086/2402272, but I'm not knowledgeable enough about CUDA to be sure, so I don't want to deploy the dupehammer.

Comment: Everything you have shown works correctly for me.  I created my own test.c which calls a wrapper function in main.c which calls the wrapper function in main_kernel.cu.  Then I manually compiled main_kernel.cu as you described, then ran your two makefiles in sequence. All stages proceeded without error and the final `Test` executable was correctly built. You'll need to provide a complete example.  You may also need to rearrange your final link command so as to put the objects first and the libraries at the end, to resolve link order issues.  But I didn't have any difficulty with your makefiles.

Comment: Strange. It must be an error on my end. Thanks for the sanity check.

Comment: You were right @RobertCrovella; the issue was indeed link order.
I knew it had to be something obvious. I can build and run successfully now.
If you want the rep from an answer, I'll gladly accept it. Otherwise I'll type something up when I get the chance.

Comment: That would be great if you can provide an answer.  As I mentioned, I was actually not able to reproduce your problem.  This is probably due to a difference in host compiler (gnu) version, which highlights the value of providing a well-defined [mcve] for many questions here on stack overflow.

Comment: @NicolajRasmussen You can also answer it yourself ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was not in compilation of the static lib, but in the linking of said library.

The problem was fixed for me by changing:

```
# Link executable
$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $(OUTDIR)$@ $(LDFLAGS) $(LIB)
```

Into:

```
# Link executable
$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $(OUTDIR)$@ $(LIB) $(LDFLAGS)
```

Such that the static lib, which is just a collection of objects, is linked with the other objects, before linking to the CUDA libs in $(LDFLAGS).

A note as well for anyone else stumbling on this in the future; it seems to be a bit dependent on the version of your compiler, whether or not this actually causes an error.